# Asp.net mvc dropdown list using ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

My table in db have fields : `Id`,`Organisation`,`Info`.

I want make dropdowm list like that:

```
<select>
  <option value='Id there'>'Organisation there'</option>...
```

I'm try to do it, using ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.Organisations = db.Organisations.ToList(); // get all fields from table using dbContext
```

and in View:

```
@Html.DropDownList('I don`t know what i shoud write here, please help')
```

How i can build dropdown list?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You would need to create a [`SelectList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) in controller action using one of the [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) available and in view just pass it DropDownList method as parameter.

In Controller do this:

```
ViewBag.Organisations = new SelectList(db.Organisations.ToList(),"Id","Organisation");
```

in `SelectList` we need to specify which property to use as `value` and which to use as `text` in the `option` tag which we are specifying in last two parameters.

and then in View you would need to use it this way:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Organization",ViewBag.Organisations as SelectList)
```

Here first parameter would be used as name of `select` element and second one will be used to populate the `option` elements in the `select`

Following is the list of overloads available for `Html.DropDownList` :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.dropdownlist%28v=vs.111%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you. Please tell me why i have error -There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Organization'?

Comment: @Html.DropDownList("Organizations", ........) Change the Organization to Organizations, it needs to match the ViewBag name, which in this case is Organizations, with a plural s.

Comment: @I.Bond are you still facing that issue ? the way i showed if you do that way i don't think you should see that error

Answer (score 6):

I recommend you to define a ViewModel for your page with a `OrganisationId` property. Thus this value will be filled when selecting an entry of the organisations dropdown list.

```
@model BCO.Models.SelectOrganisationViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "OrganisationInfo";
}

<div>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.OrganisationId,
        new SelectList(ViewBag.Organisations, "Id", "Name"))
</div>
```

The [SelectList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd505286(v=vs.118).aspx) itself expects

- the list to fill the DropDownList with
- the value ("Id")
- the text ("Name")

as parameters.

Comment: While this might answer the question and help the OP, please also try to provide a little explanation and not only code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use selectlist from viewbag as follows

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Name, ViewBag.GetData as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

here ViewBag.GetData is populated from the controller,
the controller code should be like

```
ViewBag.GetData = new SelectList(repository.GetOrganisation(), "ID", "OraganizationName");
```

Answer (score 0):

**controller**

```
ViewBag.category = new SelectList(db.CategoryMasters.ToList(), "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
```

**view**

```
 <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CategoryId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                   <div hidden>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CategoryId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", id = "categoryid" } })</div>
                        @Html.DropDownList("select", ViewBag.category as SelectList, new { @id = "category" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CategoryId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#category").change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            alert(+value)
            $("#categoryid").val(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using HTML Helpers for less hassle.

Controller:

```
 List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
 foreach (var item in fooList)
 {
       var data = new SelectListItem()
       {
           Text = item.Text,
           Value = item.Id.ToString()
       };
       list.Add(data);
  }
  var selectList = new SelectList(list,"Value","Text");
  //The 2nd parameter specifies the selected value, 
  //The 3rd parameter specifies the text to be displayed.
  ViewBag.selectList = selectList;
```

Razor:

```
<select asp-items="ViewBag.selectList" data-placeholder="Seçiniz" data-allow-clear="true" multiple="multiple">  
</select>
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score -2):

```
@model CURDInMVC.Models.StudentModel


@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.States,
                  new SelectList(ViewBag.States, "StateID", "StateName"))
```

Comment: Hi Ramavtar Rajput, Thank you for trying to help. However we would appreciate if you can elaborate a bit more your answer. Like explanning how it works, for instance what is doing the first line, defining the model, and so on. You can consult this StackOverflow  guideline on how to write a good answer here:[https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer]