# how to show viewbag data in html table by converting viewbag object to list in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

im passing list data in the viewbag from the controller . while accessing the viewbag as list getting error.

```
error - 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

getting error at this line. `ViewBag.Total_PowerList as IEnumerable<TransformerEnergyMonitoring.Models.KWHConsumption>`

[image: screenshot]

view

```
@model IEnumerable<TransformerEnergyMonitoring.Models.KWHConsumption>
    <div class="row">
     
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                    <thead class="table-header">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Date</th>
                            <th>KWH Reading</th>
                            <th>KWH Consumption</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            @foreach (var item in (ViewBag.Total_PowerList as IEnumerable<TransformerEnergyMonitoring.Models.KWHConsumption>))
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@item.timeStamp</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
    </div>
```

> dataset

```
{ timeStamp = 12/5/2020 12:00:00 AM, finalState = 47326.95, consuption = 1455.71 }
```

> Controller

```
public ActionResult KWHDateWise(RangeSelection RS)
    {
        DateTime ToDate = Convert.ToDateTime(RS.ToDate).AddDays(1);
        RS.ToDate = ToDate;

        List<KWHConsumption> kwhcon = new List<KWHConsumption>();
        
      var Total_PowerList = db.Total_Power.Where(u => u.DeviceImei == RS.DeviceImei && (u.DeviceTimeStamp >= RS.FromDate && u.DeviceTimeStamp <= RS.ToDate)).OrderByDescending(u => u.DeviceTimeStamp).ToList();

        ViewBag.Total_PowerList= Total_PowerList
.GroupBy(
    i => i.DeviceTimeStamp.Date,
    (timeStamp, dayilyData) => new { timeStamp, dayilyData })
.Select(i => new
{
    i.timeStamp,
    finalState = i.dayilyData.Max(x => x.KWH),
    consuption = (i.dayilyData.Max(x => x.KWH) - i.dayilyData.Min(x => x.KWH))
})
.ToList();
        return PartialView("~/Views/TransEnergyHistory/_KWH.cshtml", kwhcon);
    }
```

Model

```
 public class KWHConsumption
    {
       
        public DateTime timeStamp { get; set; }
        public double finalState { get; set; }
        public double consuption { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: Why would you pass with `viewbag`? You already have a `viewmodel`, just add list to that and use it.

Comment: that model is for populating other data. i need to use the viewbag only here.

Comment: And what is the error anyway? I don't see an exception thrown by framework. Are you expecting a specific output, but got something different? Please update your question to be more clear about the issue.

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'timeStamp' while im using @item.timeStamp

Comment: You may just have to bind your viewbag object to a class of the type contained in list.

Comment: I think [this is what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46341426/9340890)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are using a viewbag is a dynamic structure that doesnt care about the datatype is having inside, what you sohuld be doing is casting your datatype to your desired type here an example:

Provided this TestModel

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and this Action in the controller

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new List<TestModel>() {
            new TestModel(){
                Id = "randomId1",
                Name = "randomName1",
                Number = 2
            },
            new TestModel(){
                Id = "randomId2",
                Name = "randomName2",
                Number = 1
            },
            new TestModel(){
                Id = "randomId3",
                Name = "randomName3",
                Number = 3
            },
        };
        ViewBag.TestModels = vm;
        return View();
    }
```

In your view it should look like this

```
@foreach (var item in (ViewBag.TestModels as IEnumerable<TestModel>))
{
  <tr>
    <td>@item.Id</td>
    <td>@item.Number</td>
    <td>@item.Name</td>
  </tr>
}
```

Im assuming in your case the way you want to cast it is

```
(ViewBag.Total_PowerList as IEnumerable<TransformerEnergyMonitoring.Models.Total_Power>)
```

Comment: i have tried as u said, but getting error - 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.', can u check once my updated code

Comment: You should debug and check whether the viewbag object actually have the list. because i tested the code and it works